# How do you make video responsive for different dimensions?

Tags: css

When I use CSS to try and make my mp4 video responsive the selector will stop working at lower dimensions such as 320 x 788. It won't center, it won't resize, it is as if I have no control over it at smaller resolutions. Almost as if the selector quits working completely. I go to the chrome dev tools and the selector will not even show up most of the time? I have had zero issues with using selectors until trying to modify the size and responsiveness of this video.

Firstly, why is my selector not even working? It isn't even showing up in dev tools only with this video. Secondly, is there some special way you have to modify the size of videos to make them responsive? Thanks

```
<video  id="videofetch" controls>
    <source src="Videos\William_VS_Lab_Playing_Fetch.mp4" type="mp4">
    <source src="Videos\William_VS_Lab_Playing_Fetch.mp4" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

```
#videofetch {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px solid white; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

**Note I tried doing many different sizes for width and height.

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST**

It is not working because the video is `id="videofetch"` but in CSS you are selecting `.videofetch` which is selecting a class. for id it has to be `#videofetch`

**SECOND**

For responsive video you can use percentage for the width and make the height auto. Like so:

```
#videofetch {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px solid white; 
    width: 10%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Or even you can use **max-width**. it will go smaller if the video is smaller but never go higher than 20%.

```
#videofetch {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 2px solid white; 
    max-width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: That was a typo, I have #videofetch for my code, still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

making your video responsive can be done using [the object-fit CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) the value shall be `cover`

> The object-fit CSS property sets how the content of a replaced
>   element, such as an  or , should be resized to fit its
>   container.

**cover**

> The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
>   filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio
>   does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be
>   clipped to fit.

so just set

```
video{
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

then check you [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. Soooooooo annoying. The media quarry for an image that I posted above did not have the second bracket on the bottom, it was like this...

```
@media (min-width: 160rem) {
        .imagecontainer img {
            height: 45rem;
            margin-bottom: 5rem;
    }
```

I put in the second bracket and now it works. Man I hate typos like this!!! Thank you for your time guys.